# sqlite database error unable to open activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating an activity to get user name passwords and register them i am facing issue of sqlite exception in Member register activity can anyone point me what i am doing wrong in below code? posted updated LOGCAT

**DBHelper activity**

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "membersdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "members"; // this is your
                                                        // table name
private static final String KEY_ROW_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String KEY_FULLNAME = "fullname";
private static final String KEY_EMAILS = "email";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROW_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_USERNAME
        + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL , "
        + KEY_FULLNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + KEY_EMAILS
        + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS members");
    onCreate(db);

}
```

}

**DBAdapter activity**

```
public class DBAdapter {
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "members";
    public static final String KEY_ROW_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_FULLNAME = "fullname";
    public static final String KEY_EMAILS = "emails";

    SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    Context mCtx;
    DBHelper mDbHelper;

    public DBAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mCtx = context;
    }

    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DBHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public long register(String user, String pw, String name, String email) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, user);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, pw);
        initialValues.put(KEY_FULLNAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_EMAILS, email);

        return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean Login(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " WHERE username=? AND password=?", new String[] { username,
                password });
        if (mCursor != null) {
            if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**main activity calling DBadapter**

```
public class MembersActivity extends Activity {
    DBAdapter dbAdapter;
    EditText txtUserName;
    EditText txtPassword;
    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnRegister;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        txtUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_user);
        txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);

        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(this);
        dbAdapter.open();

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtUserName.getWindowToken(), 0);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtPassword.getWindowToken(), 0);
                String username = txtUserName.getText().toString();
                String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
                if (username.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {
                    try {

                        if (dbAdapter.Login(username, password)) {
                            Toast.makeText(MembersActivity.this,
                                    "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MembersActivity.this,
                                    "Invalid username or password",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MembersActivity.this,
                                "Some problem occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();

                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MembersActivity.this,
                            "Username or Password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent opencont = new Intent("com.ideals.ideal.MEMBERSREGISTER");
                startActivity(opencont);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
09-29 21:46:07.577: I/Database(555): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table members has no column named emails
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555): Error inserting username=hello emails=hello password=hello fullname=hello
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table members has no column named emails: , while compiling: INSERT INTO members(username, emails, password, fullname) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:41)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1149)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1569)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1426)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at com.ideals.ideal.DBAdapter.register(DBAdapter.java:42)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at com.ideals.ideal.MembersRegister$1.onClick(MembersRegister.java:50)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-29 21:46:07.587: E/Database(555):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where is your table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have these

```
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "members"; // this is your table name
private static final String KEY_ROW_ID = "_id"; 
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
```

in `DBHelper`

Then Your query should look like this

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =  "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" 
            + KEY_ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL , " +
            KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL );";
```

Comment: thanks raghunandan, can i  add fields name, email and authorization code in this table??

Comment: @monikasingh oh yes just make sure your syntax is right and you are good to code

Comment: @monikasingh what is the new error? follow the example here http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: @monikasingh `table members has no column named emails: , while compiling: INSERT INTO members(username, emails, password, fullname) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)` your table doe snot have a column by the name emails. make sure you have one

Comment: @monikasingh its id,username,password,email when you create your table. check the order and the synctax make sure your syntax and column names match

Comment: i added that in db helper and adapter please cross check updated codes

Comment: @monikasingh you have this in logcat `username=hello emails=hello password=hello fullname=hello` is your order of column names right? its is  `id (autoincrement),username,fullname,password,email` when you create your table

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing the table name, try it like this:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "membersdb";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE members (_id integer primary key autoincrement, username text not null, password text not null);";

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS members");
    onCreate(db);

  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned the table name. The logcat is also focussing on that:

```
 09-29 20:17:09.747: E/AndroidRuntime(372): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": syntax error: CREATE TABLE  (_id integer primary key autoincrement,username text not null,password text not null);
```

So specify the table name.